# Finding and using memory offsets in an existing program?

Tags: memory, automation, reverse-engineering

Most game botting applications use a series of memory offsets they have found for that particular version of a game client to facilitate botting.  They might have a memory offset for health, x/y position, etc.  Every time the game releases an update the offsets for the various pieces of information the bot program uses must be re-found and updated as well.

I'm interested in writing a Solitaire bot as a pet project.  If you look here, mmoglider (a commercial bot) has already accomplished this as a demo for their botting program (which normally is used to bot WoW): [YouTube video of MMOGlider botting Vista Solitaire.](http://ca.youtube.com/watch?v=f7Oy9fOwyr4)

What is a common method of accurately locating various useful memory offsets?  How might I go about locating the memory offset that points to the "deck" in the solitaire program and use that to determine what cards are on the stack?  I know from experience with the glider guys that once they were able to locate the offsets for the deck itself they said that every card value for the entire deck was there.

***So, does anyone have any experience with reverse engineering and pulling memory offsets out of existing programs? And once you have those offsets how to be able to pull and read the values from that "Deck" structure in memory?***

Answer (score 10):

Typically there are two approaches to such tasks.  For simplicity, let us consider a game with an integer amount of "health" for the player.

The first is to manipulate the process memory while the program is running.  This is good for finding known values.  When you have 100 health in a game, search the memory space for 100 (most likely as an integer) and record every location it is found.  Then when your health changes to 99, cross-search those same locations to see which have changed appropriately.  Continue until you have narrowed down the precise location(s) of the health variable.  In most modern games what you will actually find is a dynamically allocated memory address that is part of a struct.  That struct will be referenced by a pointer within the program, you then have to search within the program memory for values that may be a pointer to the space near the health variable, and repeat the narrowing-down process over multiple game runs to establish the position of the pointer to the data that you want.  This is the method most useful for classic PC and console games, particularly any game where the memory space is small and easy to manipulate.

The second method requires you to disassemble the application binary (I use [IDA Pro](http://www.hex-rays.com/idapro/) for this), then locate functions that are known to use the data that you want.  For example, say you see "Health: 99" on the screen.  Search the binary for the "Health: " string, then find references to that string (you will likely find a call to sprintf or similar) and see what other memory locations those same functions reference, this will usually lead you to the "health" variable or the struct containing it.  This is the method most common in more modern games, with massive memory spaces and more advanced programming practices.